# Azure policy append ipSecurityRestriction

Tags: azure, azure-policy

I'm trying to append restriction to App Service networking IP Access Restrictions:

[image]

This is my policy effect:

```
"then": {
  "effect": "append",
  "details": [
    {
      "field": "Microsoft.Web/sites/siteConfig.ipSecurityRestrictions[*]",
      "value": 
        {
          "IpAddress": "0.0.0.0/0",
          "action": "Deny",
          "tag": "Default",
          "priority": 9999,
          "name": "Test Rule"
        }
    }
  ]
}
```

But instead of appending to the existing array of restrictions, it overwrites it with this single rule.
Why is that?

Comment: Can you add complete template/policy, so that I can try it out!

Comment: https://pastebin.com/PCgWDJUx
This is my policy for now, but the 'if' shouldn't really matter as long as it gets triggered - the append effect doesn't take place, instead there's a replace effect.

Comment: When does the overwriting happen? Is it when you first create the site, or when you update another property on site? My guess is that the Azure Portal does not include the existing ipSecurityRestrictions array when updating other properties (you can check this in dev tools), so Policy is appending and therefore overwriting existing rules.

Comment: Yea, the overwrite happens only when modifying other properties from the portal - when I'm modifying them via azure cli it works properly. By dev tools you mean resources.azure.com?
If that's the way it works is it a bug, or should I fix something in the policy?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can gather is that the Azure RM API does actually consider objects within an array to be distinct values. Thus when it sees the ipSecurityRestrictions array come it instead of doing an incremental update, it just replaces them. This doesn't just affect App Services either, found that KV Access Policies are also afflicted by the same condition...

I know that this is an old issue, but hopefully provides some closure.

Edit: Found [Azure Policy Issue 682](https://github.com/Azure/azure-policy/issues/682) on GitHub which does into the api action being leveraged.